# How to get the value of an element through xslt(a complex query)

Tags: xml, xslt

**XML:**

```
<Book>
   <Title>blahblah</Title>
   <Title>
    <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle><subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>asdfg
   </Title>
   <Title>
    <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>jhuk<subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>refsdw
  </Title>
  <Title>
   <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>fdgfjhdc<subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>
  </Title>
 </Book>
```

Output Result should be:

```
 <Title>blahblah</Title>
 <Title>asdfg</Title>
 <Title>jhukrefsdw</Title>
 <Title>fdgfjhdc</Title>
```

Comment: Which one?  Just the first one (with no subtitle children) or do you want to know how to extract the direct text from all of them?

Comment: see what i added..also add more details for your question so others know what you are looking for.

Comment: @Ian : direct text from all of them

Comment: Is there any probable solution for this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach here may be simply to strip out the `subtitle` elements entirely.  The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!-- identity template - copies everything as-is unless overridden -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ignore (i.e. delete) subtitle elements -->
  <xsl:template match="subtitle" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

would produce output of

```
<Book>
   <Title>blahblah</Title>
   <Title>
    asdfg
   </Title>
   <Title>
    jhukrefsdw
  </Title>
  <Title>
   fdgfjhdc
  </Title>
 </Book>
```

If you want to fix up the whitespace then it might be sufficient to add a third template

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
</xsl:template>
```

and tell the stylesheet to indent the output

```
<xsl:output indent="yes" />
```

which would then produce

```
<Book>
  <Title>blahblah</Title>
  <Title>asdfg</Title>
  <Title>jhukrefsdw</Title>
  <Title>fdgfjhdc</Title>
</Book>
```

Comment: Thanks.. Ian, This works perfectly, you are such a genius man,, i have tried each and and every possible way to resolve this but couldn't find the solution but you solution works perfectly. Thanks a lot, :)

Comment: what needs to be done to get below output,Now i want the value of subtitle attributes as well:<Title subtitle="">blahblah</Title>
 <Title subtitle="bcdfbcdf">asdfg</Title>
 <Title  subtitle="bcdfbcdf">jhukrefsdw</Title>
 <Title subtitle="bcdfbcdf">fdgfjhdc</Title>

Comment: @Ankit your original question has now been answered and the answer accepted, so you would be better off asking a new Stack Overflow question for this new (different) problem rather than editing this question and making the existing correct answers invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a specific element by its index

```
/Book/Title[1]/text()
```

Comment: i want the value of all Title elements

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. See this.

**XML:**

```
<Book>
 <Title>blahblah</Title>
 <Title>
   <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>
   <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>blahblah
 </Title>
 <Title>
  <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>blah
  <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>blah
 </Title>
 <Title>
   <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>blahblah
   <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>
 </Title>
</Book>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
   <xsl:template match="Book">
      <xsl:value-of select="Title[text() = 'blahblah']" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
blahblah
```

Comment: If you notice the position of text 'blah' is not uniform under 'Title' element, that's the main challenge.

Comment: The text 'blah' is just for example it may be different under different levels of 'Title' element.In first 'Title' element text is just enclosed in 'Title' element but in subsequent 'Title' elements position of 'Blah' is not uniform,somewhere it is just befor the </Title>, somewhere it is between the child elements i.e. <subtitle>.I hope it is clear now.

Comment: <Book>
 <Title>blahblah</Title>
 <Title>
   <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>
   <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>asdfg
 </Title>
 <Title>
  <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>jhuk
  <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>refsdw
 </Title>
 <Title>
   <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>fdgfjhdc
   <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>
 </Title>
</Book>

Result should be like:

<Title>blahblah</Title>
<Title>asdfg</Title>
<Title>jhukrefsdw</Title>
<Title>fdgfjhdc</Title>

Comment: Is there any probable solution for this query?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
   <xsl:template match="//Title">
      <Title>
         <xsl:for-each select="text()">
           <xsl:value-of select="." />
         </xsl:for-each>
      </Title>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: For the second `Title` this would give you the string "bcdfbcdfasdfg[newline][three spaces]" - the `value-of` an element is the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes, not just the direct children.

Comment: yeah that's what he wants. For all children and grand children. You can skip the newlines and extra spaces with some function I guess. normalize-space(/) ?

Comment: Otherwise if you insist you could do:

Comment: No, he said he wants just the "asdfg" for the second title - the direct text node children, not the text nodes inside the subtitles.

Comment: then, wouldn't Title/text() be enough ?

Comment: In XSLT 1.0, `<xsl:value-of select="text()" />` would only give you the value of the _first_ text node, you'd need to use `<xsl:apply-templates select="text()" />` or a for-each to get the text from all of them.

Comment: yeah, Ian got me right, I just want the text value of Title tag not the values enclose in <subtitle>.